# **I Get This Error:** Makefile:1: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, runtime-error

**I Searched For Help On** Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
One Help But Makefile:**1**: *** missing separator.  Stop. Had No Good, Heres My Code:

```
Kaizen ~/so_test $ cat -e -t -v mk.t
ASM=nasm

SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
    cp $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    truncate -s 1440k $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin: $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm -t bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
```

idk
a

a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a
a

Comment: If not check your makefile for trailing spaces or tabs.

Comment: @Andreas I'm Using Terminal.